# How to get selected chip choice values in flutter

Tags: flutter

I've searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find the exact solution. How to get a list of selected Chips items
I am passing the list of the object for option list values but unable to get the index of the selected item in `onChanged` method

```
          Container(
            child: FormField<List<Hashtag>>(
              autovalidate: true,
              initialValue: hashtagSelectedList,
              onSaved: (value) {
                Utility.showToast(value.toString());
                //hashtagSelectedList[0].hashtag = value.toString();
              },
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please select some categories';
                }
                if (value.length > 5) {
                  return "Can't select more than 5 categories";
                }
                return null;
              },
              builder: (state) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: ChipsChoice<Hashtag>.multiple(
                        value: state.value,
                        options: ChipsChoiceOption.listFrom<Hashtag, Hashtag>(
                          source: _hashtags,
                          value: (i, v) => v,
                          label: (i, v) => v.hashtag.toString(),
                        ),
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          if (val.length > 5) {
                            Utility.showToast(
                                "Can't select more than 5 categories");
                            return;
                          }
                          state.didChange(val);
                        },
                        itemConfig: ChipsChoiceItemConfig(
                          showCheckmark: false,
                          selectedColor: Colors.indigo,
                          selectedBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                          unselectedColor: Colors.indigo,
                          unselectedBorderOpacity: .3,
                        ),
                        isWrapped: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 15),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          state.errorText ?? state.value.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: state.hasError
                                  ? Colors.redAccent
                                  : Colors.green),
                        )),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),

 Option list - List<Hashtag> _hashtags; 
 Initial list - List<Hashtag> hashtagSelectedList; 

Model -
   class Hashtag {
   int id;
   String hashtag;
  int status;
  bool isSelected = false;

  Hashtag();

  Hashtag.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json[ApiKeys.id] ?? 0;
    hashtag = json[ApiKeys.hashtag] ?? '';
    status = json[ApiKeys.status] ?? 0;
  }
}

Please give me solutions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Abhijit Rajmane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8847579/abhijit-rajmane) Try this for your case:

```
List<Category> _selectedCats = [];
  List<Category> _categories = [
    new Category(id: "001", name: "Cat 001"),
    new Category(id: "002", name: "Cat 002"),
    new Category(id: "003", name: "Cat 003"),
  ];
```

Widget for the given categories:

```
Container(
      child: ChipsChoice<Category>.multiple(
          value: _selectedCats,
          options: ChipsChoiceOption.listFrom<Category, Category>(
            source: _categories,
            value: (i, v) => v,
            label: (i, v) => v.name,
          ),
          onChanged: (val) {
            //val.forEach((category) {
            //  print("${category.id} - ${category.name}");
            //});
            setState(() => _selectedCats = val);
          }),
    )
```

For more example refer to the [chips_choice](https://pub.dev/packages/chips_choice) package examples.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you,but how to achieve for object list,i want get selected object list.I have already done your given code for string list but what about for object list.Please give me solution..