# how I can get The value of The Chip when the user Pressed or select from the list of chip widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a function that allows chips to scroll horizontally over horizontal space. To implement this function, the Row component was developed in SingleChildScrollView. I want the value of chips button when the user pressed one of the chips,   onpressed does not work for me??

```
here is my Build method where is use the chips

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.useridforinfo);
    print(widget.usertypeforinfo);
    return Scaffold(
     key: _key,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange.shade900,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: rowChips(),
          ),
        ],
      ),

      );
  }
```

---

```
 rowChips(){
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        chipForRow("Aids Abeba",Color(0xFFff8a65)),
        chipForRow("Adama",Color(0xFF9575cd)),
        chipForRow("Hawasssa",Color(0xFF4db6ac)),
        chipForRow("Bishoftu",Color(0xFF5cda65)),
        chipForRow("Aids Abeba",Color(0xFFff8a65)),
        chipForRow("Adama",Color(0xFF9575cd)),
        chipForRow("Hawasssa",Color(0xFF4db6ac)),
        chipForRow("Bishoftu",Color(0xFF5cda65)),
      ],
    );
  }
```

---

```
here is my method to Create the chips

  Widget chipForRow(String label, Color color){
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
      child: Chip(
        labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
         avatar: CircleAvatar(
           backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
           child:  Text(label[0].toUpperCase())
         ),
        label: Text(
          label,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: color,
        elevation: 6.0,
        shadowColor: Colors.grey[60],
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),

      ),

    );

  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833658/6280156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the Chip widget with a GestureDetector Widget and make use of onTap parameter like so:

**THE SIMPLER APPROACH**

```
...

GestureDetector(
    child: Chip(
      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      avatar: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
          child: Text(label.toString()[0].toUpperCase())),
      label: Text(
        label.toString(),
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: color,
      elevation: 6.0,
      shadowColor: Colors.grey[60],
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
    ),
    onTap: () {
      //Prints the label of each tapped chip
      print(label);
    },
  ),

 ...
```

**ANOTHER APPROACH**

***Create a List to hold the ChipForRow Objects***

```
//List to hold Chip Objects
  final List<ChipForRow> chips = [
    ChipForRow("Aids Abeba", Color(0xFFff8a65)),
    ChipForRow("Adama", Color(0xFF9575cd)),
    ChipForRow("Hawasssa", Color(0xFF4db6ac)),
    ChipForRow("Bishoftu", Color(0xFF5cda65)),
    ChipForRow("Aids Abeba", Color(0xFFff8a65)),
    ChipForRow("Adama", Color(0xFF9575cd)),
    ChipForRow("Hawasssa", Color(0xFF4db6ac)),
    ChipForRow("Bishoftu", Color(0xFF5cda65)),
  ];
```

***Create a Stateful Widget class, ChipFirRow** instead of a function*

```
class ChipForRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final Color color;

  ChipForRow(this.label, this.color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Chip(
          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          avatar: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
              child: Text(label.toString()[0].toUpperCase())),
          label: Text(
            label.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: color,
          elevation: 6.0,
          shadowColor: Colors.grey[60],
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          print(label);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With the **second approach, we can rebuild any the **ChipForRow** widget whenever it is selected or deselected, indicating when a chip is selected or deselected by *adding/removing* it's label from a list of Strings.

Comment: Thank you? Is it possible to change the background color of the chip when the user press, I use a Normal chip,  In My Above code i want to chip change it's background color when the user Press them

Comment: Thank you brother,  GestureDetector() Works fine, but I Want to change the background color of the Pressed chip, when the user Press the chip,

Comment: IS IT Possible to Select more than  one chip, without  making the chip Filter Chips, I want to use A normal chip, but also I want the user to select more than one chip at a atime

Comment: @bebe, It is very possible to select more than one Chip. But first you'll have to change the approach to your implementation a bit. I'll edit my answer to reflect my solution

Comment: your code works fine but I want to know how to add two(2) thing into your code,            first, I want to change the color of the chip when the user Selected, and Second, I want the user to select more than two-chip at a time, Please add this Two things into your Answer, Thank you for Your Help in Advance,

Comment: @bebe, I have edited the code; where I converted your chipForRow Widget from a function to a *Stateful Widget*. This will enable you to rebuild a single chip whenever it is selected or deselected.